How to Solve External Connection Issues When Making API Calls in Laravel on OVH Shared Hosting?
I'm working on a Laravel 11 project with PHP 8.3, hosted on an OVH Pro shared server. The project involves making API calls to write data to a blockchain. This API call is scheduled to run once a day using Laravel's scheduler, which is managed by a cron job on the OVH server.
The API call must occur at a fixed time but not necessarily through the scheduler. The issue I'm encountering is that OVH blocks the use of cURL on their shared servers. I currently use the Laravel Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http facade for HTTP requests. However, when I try to execute the command, I get the following error:
In PendingRequest.php line 939:
  cURL error 7: Failed to connect to stagingblockchain.izzymobility.com port 443: Connection refused (see https://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-errors.html) for https://stagingblockchain.izzymobility.com/api/auth/login

Notably, the API call works fine within the project itself.
I contacted OVH, and they told me they block most cURL requests.
Solutions I've Tried:

Modifying the API Call Method:

Using Guzzle directly instead of Laravel's HTTP facade (which is based on Guzzle), and switching the handler to stream instead of cURL.

Investigating the socket handler but couldn't find enough information to implement it.


Using plain PHP


Modifying How the Scheduler Executes the Call:

Using a job instead of a command.
Creating a controller with a GET route to execute the call.

The call works when I visit the URL directly but not when the scheduler executes it.
Instantiating the controller, since OVH blocks even cURL to the server's address.


Attempting to access the route from a JavaScript file using fetch.



Despite these efforts, I'm out of potential solutions and considering switching servers. Does anyone have any ideas or suggestions for other approaches I could try to resolve this issue?
Thank you!
Edit:
Curl isn't actually the issue; OVH blocks all outgoing requests (except for GitHub/GitLab, for example). I misunderstood their response, which was:

The error encountered indicates that you cannot connect to the remote server because we block certain outgoing connections

So it's unrelated to curl.

"is that OVH blocks the use of cURL on their shared servers" - Looks like an issue for the support of OVH. Did you already try to open a ticket over there?

Are you sure they are blocking requests made via cURL specifically? That doesn't sound like a thing that would make much sense to begin with. They probably rather block HTTP requests to most destinations in general, independent of what technique or tool you'd actually use to try and make that request.

Not a very helpful comment, but maybe find a new shared hosting provider.

What happens if you skip using cURL? As this is tagged with [tag:laravel-scheduler]: did you try to run this without the scheduler? Is this working better? "Notably, the API call works fine within the project itself." - what exactly does that mean? Requesting that URL works when doing it in any other way?

@DarkBee Yes, I opened a ticket, and they told me: The error encountered indicates that you cannot connect to the remote server because we block certain outgoing connections. So, I'm trying to find other ways if possible.

@CBroe actually I think you're right, upon rereading OVH's response: The error encountered indicates that you cannot connect to the remote server because we block certain outgoing connections. They don't specify "with curl," so trying something other than curl won't make a difference (I also got an error using Guzzle's stream handler).

@TobyAllen I think you're right, but it's not convenient for me :'(

@NicoHaase It still doesn't work even when I don't use curl; that was a dead end. Yes, it works when I don't use the scheduler (I created a GET route that triggers the call). From what I understand, OVH blocks outgoing calls via SSH (which the scheduler triggers) but not within the project. I tried calling the route via the scheduler (instantiating the controller since Http::get() doesn't work due to OVH blocking even intra-project calls), but I still get the same error.

If the connections are blocked by OVH then I'm afraid there is no other way than move to another provider. Strange they would block certain network stuff on a VPS tho.. Maybe because it's related to blockchain tho

@DarkBee Yes, sorry, I clicked send before asking ChatGPT to translate ^^ Don't you think there's another way to schedule the call without using the scheduler and a cron job? I have a GET route that I can call.

Please add all clarification to your question by editing it. If you learned that this is not related to cURL, remove that tag. If you know that these requests work when running from a webserver process (and not when running from shell), why not use that: add the API requests to a controller, call that controller using wget from a cronjob

@NicoHaase Thank you for these details, it's my first time posting on Stack Overflow. I will edit the question. Regarding wget, I got the following result:
--2024-06-27 10:22:50--  https://dev.conciergerie.ovh/[my route]
Resolving dev.conciergerie.ovh (dev.conciergerie.ovh)... 164.132.235.17, 2001:41d0:301::23
Connecting to dev.conciergerie.ovh (dev.conciergerie.ovh)|164.132.235.17|:443... failed: Connection refused.
Connecting to dev.conciergerie.ovh (dev.conciergerie.ovh)|2001:41d0:301::23|:443... failed: Address family not supported by protocol.
